# MSIX Packaging Tool: App going from x86 to x64

Tags: uwp, msix

I've been working lately with an old app which was mainly built some years ago in x86 architecture. I've been researching about using MSIX Packaging Tool, and so far I've managed to package my application. The problem is that the new package is built for x64, not for x86, and so when I install the app through the MSIX, it gets installed in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps, which as far as I know, works for x64 apps. When I try to launch it, I get the error "The parameter is incorrect". So far, I've tried using chkdsk to see if there was a problem with the disk, but it seems that everything is fine. Also, I tried to get inside the folder, but due to the computer being a working computer, I can't modify the permits to get inside it. I don't know how to fix the problem, or even where's the problem (disk problem? x86 app installing in x64 folder?), so any help would be nice.

Thanks, and sorry for any grammar errors.

Comment: May I know how you packaged your old app and what type of your old app? Did you follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package) to package it?

Comment: It is a WPF app, (using c# and xaml), and yes, i followed that document to create the package.

Comment: You can go to this [MSIX forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix/ct-p/MSIX) to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

We've converted multiple x86 apps and this was never a problem. I suspect that maybe your application requires some shortcut arguments (currently not supported by default when using the MSIX Packaging Tool) as mentioned in several [discussions on MS's MSIX forums](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix-packaging-and-tools/msix-command-line-argument/m-p/304080/highlight/true#M208).

Try using another free tool to convert the package, like the [Advanced Installer Express edition.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html)  Know you can also easily get it from the [MS Store.](https://www.microsoft.com/ro-ro/p/advanced-installer-express/9n4vqdj7ltb8?rtc=1)

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*